# Facebook SSO , differentiating the login and wall post messages

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-emulator

I have made a sample for posting on Facebook using the basic Facebook library provided at developer.facebook.com and it works just fine with SSO,

```
    btnPostOnFb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        {
                facebook.authorize(FBIntegrationSampleActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"}, new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        if(values!=null && values.containsKey("access_token")){
                            postOnWall("NEW POST from" +count+"Android -Anuj");
                            Log.e("post on wall", "WALLPOST");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESSFULLY POSTED MSG ON WALL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if(values!=null)
                            Log.e("LOGINE SUCCESS", "LOGIN SUCCESS");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                        Log.e("onFBERROR", "ONFBERROR");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        Log.e("on DESI ERROR", "ON_ERROR");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.e("onCANCEL", "ONCANCEL");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Which successfully posts on the Facebook wall, what i want is, I need to show the user that he has successfully signed in, and a message would be posted there after.

The Issue i face is the `onComplete(Bundle values)` method is called for both successful login and for successful post, how can i differentiate between both of them, is there a `key` in the Bundle values that can help to find the differnence?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: implement another listener for posting any status on wall same as you do on login.

Comment: why you need to do something in onComplete(), just do whatever you want with wallpost in your postToWall() method only.

Comment: check my edit will solve your problem

Comment: Check my post , let me know if you need any help @Some one Some where

Comment: I did see it, but i really am fairly new to this, and I just need to first show a "login success" message, I really dont find where I can get a login success call back.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11936/android-lite come and join i found some tricky solution for u which i can explain at chat

Comment: very well @khan, it works just fine for me as well, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are using for Authentication and Posting. No need to do like this :

For Authentication use

```
facebook.authorize(a, PERMISSIONS,-1,new LoginListener());
```

And for posting :

1) Without Dialog `facebook.request(parameters)`

2) With Dialog

```
facebook.dialog(this,"stream.publish",parameters,new TestUiServerListener());


    public class TestUiServerListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
        if (postId != null) {
            new AsyncFacebookRunner(ZValues.authenticatedFacebook).request(postId,new TestPostRequestListener());
        } else {
            Post_Message_Title.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void onCancel() {
    }

    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class TestPostRequestListener implements RequestListener {
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            String postId = json.getString("id");
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 
                        successLoginShowDialog();  // Dialog after Login succeeds
                }
            });
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, final Object state) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            final Object state) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onIOException(IOException e, final Object state) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            final Object state) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Just create a method successLoginShowDialog() and show whatever you want ,

If Post is success , In TestPostRequestListener below Thread will be called , so do all stuffs in this Thread :

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
            successLoginShowDialog();  // Dialog after Login succeeds
        }
});
```

Comment: @venky ,I just want to show a pop up message that "you have logged in successfully" , where do you think i can go ahead to achieve that.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Edited , check my post

Answer (score 0):

to postOnWall() you can get its response:

```
public void postToWall(String message) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", message);
        parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
        try {
            fbObj.request("me");
            String response = fbObj.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("")
                    || response.equals("false")) {
                // showToast("Blank response.");
                Toast.makeText(context, "blank response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Message posted to your facebook wall!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I still dont get it, how do i get two different notifications for login and for posting on wall , is there some key like "access_token" that can help me find that the onComplete() is for login / for wall post success.

Comment: first do login then get its response in onComplete method and then call the method i have written same as where you do and you will get response of posting on wall too..

Comment: `first do login then get its response in onComplete method` where do u think I can get the "Login Success" message on successful login, don't I need some key to fetch it from the Bundle object , do you know which key it is? am i able to make my self clear?